# How do I extract a CSR text in between string using Regex perl?

Tags: regex, perl, openssl, csr

I would need to extract the Subject Alternative Name from the whole extracted CSR information. Example below:

```html
some text........
                  c9:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:98:a3:22:4e:68:f0:44:
                    8a:ef
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        Attributes:
        Requested Extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:DNSName1234, IP Address: 192.168.0.0
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        2e:00:0d:08:ea:04:12:de:58:88:f0:50:72:d5:b3:03:9d:14:
        e9:d6:f2:75:4e:e1:64:57:0e:a8:61:as:55:2e:75:e7:72:0b:
        3d:db:a8:49:68:9f:11:b7:5a:a6:6k:49:25:ed:bc:e2:00:00:

some text...
```

I would need to extract the **DNS:DNSName1234, IP Address: 192.168.0.0** from the sample text above.
Basically what I'm thinking is to get  *X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:* and *Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption* as the two strings and get the text in between

here's some of my snippet:

```
my $SubjAltName = `openssl req -in /opt2/myfile/perllib/custom/OpenSSL/certreq.csr -text -noout`; #or die "Could not get SAN";

my $SANtxt = $SubjAltName =~ /X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:(.|\n)*? Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption/;
print $SANtxt;
```

Should print **DNS:DNSName1234, IP Address: 192.168.0.0**. if there is none, then the output is blank.

Appreciate your help, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will extract  your requirement I perceive, the string is predefined, so no need of IP Address validation or other tweaks:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $out= 'some text........
                  c9:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:98:a3:22:4e:68:f0:44:
                    8a:ef
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        Attributes:
        Requested Extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:DNSName1234, IP Address: 192.168.0.0
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        2e:00:0d:08:ea:04:12:de:58:88:f0:50:72:d5:b3:03:9d:14:
        e9:d6:f2:75:4e:e1:64:57:0e:a8:61:as:55:2e:75:e7:72:0b:
        3d:db:a8:49:68:9f:11:b7:5a:a6:6k:49:25:ed:bc:e2:00:00:

some text...';

my ($string) =grep{/DNS:/}split(/\n/,$out);
if($string){ 
$string=~s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
} 
else{
$string =  ' ';
};
print "$string \n";#prints DNS:DNSName1234, IP Address: 192.168.0.0
```